# How to replace 'null' in Java

Tags: java, fortify

Is there any other way to **replace 'null' for HP Fortify null deference fix**. null is passing to one of my HQL queries so I can't use 'StringUtil.EMPTY' to replace null.

```
setAdminCurriculums(getAgencyBA().getCurriculumListByCompany(**null**, false));

*
*
*
*
```

The null value is passing to below code.

```
public String getCurriculumListByCompany(String company, String isCorrect){
*
*
*
  String hql = "select id from UserData where userId = " + company;
*
*
}
```

Comment: what do you want `null` to become ?  You are using its value to select from a DB

Comment: What is the first line supposed to do? Does the `getCurriculumListByCompany` method return anything when called with `null` as a first parameter?

Comment: And why is a UserID a company?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to happen when the value 'null' is passed.
If you can not guarantee that 'null' will never be passed, you will need to deal with it in the method where it can occur.

For example, if you want it to be an empty String, in the method you can check:

```
 company = company != null ? company : "";
```

Since you are dealing with a query a bit further on, I suppose this is actually not the wanted behaviour. But what do you want to do? If no company is passed, do you want it to be any company?

```
String hql = "Select id from UserData";
if(company != null) {
     String hql += " where userId = " + company;
 }
```

Passing a Null value does not need to be a problem in itself. You should have the code deal with this in an appropriate way - but from your description I can not infer what the correct solution would be. If you want a *null* value to not be allowed, you could give it an `@NotNull` annotation so it will throw an error if this would happen.

```
 public String getCurriculumListByCompany(@NotNull String company, String isCorrect){
```

Or, alternatively, throw the error yourself inside the method as a guard statement:

```
 public String getCurriculumListByCompany(String company, String isCorrect){
      if(company == null){
           throw new RuntimeException("Company should not be null!");
       }
       ..
 }
```